# c# Complex chart in ReportView

Tags: c#, charts, reporting

I need to make **chart** in **ReportView** like this:

[image]

I need **two** lines with different **DataSources** in one **chart**.

Answer (score 1):

Visifire has capabilities to create this complex chart in Report View. You can try adding [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/wpf_charts.php) chart in Report View. A Chart can accepts N number of DataSeries where each DataSeries is a line/spline graph. DataSource can be set for each DataSeries.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: But, how can i do it without Visifire ?

Comment: Well if you don't want to use any separate charting component in your application then you need to do lots of calculation based on your data and draw the graph in the screen. In that case you can calculate max and min value out of your two data set and draw x and y axis and then finally draw two spline graphs based on your two data set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29 . Yes you can use graphics primitives like Line, Point, Ellipse, Bezier curve etc to draw the graph.